# Callback method C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I need to create a callback method for my Commit method, just to know when it finished.
So anyone know how to do that, how can I be able to call the commmit, then subscribe to the callback event/method to do other stuff when it is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, in C#, you would do this via an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx).  The most common method for handling this would be to use the [Event-based Asynchronous Programming model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx).  This would define your API, by convention, as:

```
public void YourMethodAsync() {}  // starts your method
public Event EventHandler<YourEventArgs> YourMethodCompleted; // Event used to receive completion notification
```

That being said, if you're developing for .NET 4, you might want to consider designing your method around the `Task` or `Task<T>` class, instead.  Instead of creating a callback, you can return a `Task` directly.  This allows your user to create a *task continuation* that runs when the operation completes.  In addition, future versions of C# will allow the user to take advantage of the *await* and *async* keywords currently in CTP form to ease development.

Comment: sorry to ask you this, but do you have a full code that describe the .net 4 approach. thanks for your reply

Comment: @Waleed: See my blog series on TPL: http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/  I cover this in detail...

Answer (score 3):

Define the Commit method to accept parameter of type Action.

And then you can pass a function as callback parameter to the Commit method.

e.g:

```
public void Commit(Action CommitCallback)
{
    //Code to handle Commit
    CommitCallback();
}


.
.
.
.
//Somewhere in your code:

Commit(()=>{ Console.WriteLine("Commit finished");});
```

or have a method defined

```
Commit(CommitPostProcessing);

public void CommitPostProcessing()
{
    //Some code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use events but they can get messy quickly. So to use a callback let's say  that your Commit method's signature currently looks something like this,

```
void Commit() { }
```

You can add a callback easily using a delegate, let's say you accept a parameter of type CommitResult in your callback,

```
void Commit(Action<CommitResult> callback) { }
```

You can use this multiple ways, first is with a lambda,

```
obj.Commit(result => Console.Write(result));
```

or with another method,

```
obj.Commit(CallbackMethod);

void CallbackMethod(CommitResult result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, you can use events, here is a primitive example:

```
public MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler Comitted;

    public void Commit()
    {
        //committing code
        if (Comitted != null)
        {
            Committed(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

The reason we check for `null` of `Comitted` is simply because it is a possibility that there be no subscribers. So, how to subscribe? You need a method whose signature matches that of the `EventHandler` type of the event, when this method fires it is your indicator that `Commit` completed, then using an instance of the type you need to delegate the event:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.Committed += OnCommitted;
myClass.Commit();

void OnCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //event handler code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use events.

```
 public class LongOperation
{
    public event EventHandler Committed;

    public void Commit()
    {
        //Do you stuff here.
        //Call OnComitted once finished.
        OnCommitted(new EventArgs());
    }

    protected void OnCommitted(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = Committed;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Use following code from calling object:

```
        LongOperation operation = new LongOperation();
        operation.Committed += new EventHandler(operation_Committed);
        operation.Commit();
...

    void operation_Committed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do extra stuff here....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an Observer Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern and subscribe

You could use a delegate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx to call

You could create an event that gets triggered http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx and invoke it

Probably some other ways, those are the three off the top of my head.